# C - call function with dynamic number of arguments

Tags: c, arguments

I have a C function with a specific number of arguments (not a varargs function). Eg:

```
void testfunction(int a, int b, int c);
```

This function is a black-box, so I can't modify it.

In the main function I have an array containing all the arguments that I want to pass to my "testfunction". Eg:

```
void main() {
    int args[] = {1, 2, 3};
    ...
}
```

Assuming that I don't know in advance what is the number of arguments that my "testfunction" will accept (because this function can change, depending on the function that I want to test), how can I call "testfunction" with the arguments in the array dynamically defined?

I have some experience in Ruby, it would be the equivalent of

```
def test(a, b, c)
    ...
end
array = [1,2,3]
test(*array)
```

Thanks you a lot!

Comment: There is no standard C way for doing this.  You'll have to resort to machine-specific assembly tricks or have a long case switch for each number of arguments you want to support.

Comment: As long as your calling convention is caller-cleanup, you can call a function with more arguments than it needs/wants.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something (if so, sorry), but why can't your test function take a pointer to an array and a number of arguments?  `void testfunction(void *arrayPtr, int numArgs)`?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if `_Generic` would help.

Comment: @Mawg the problem is that "testfunction" is a black-box, I can't control it, and I should be able to change it whenever I want. Or, anyway, I can change something, but i need it to keep behaving the exact same way. So, if I change its prototype (as you suggest, for example), I would have to change all references to parameters in the body of the function every time I change "testfunction", which is a little annoying.

Comment: I see your point - and, actually, I suspected it, but your question didn't (to my reading (ymmv)) explicitly state that. Maybe a an edit to the question would help others to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't achieve exactly what you want, but, you can get close, if you have a limit to the number of arguments that you want to transfer. You'll also loose some type security. Here's how to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*tf_t)(); // `tf_t` can accept any number of arguments

void tf1(int a) { printf("tf1: %d\n", a); }
void tf2(int a, int b) { printf("tf2: %d, %d\n", a,b); }
void tf3(int a, int b, int c) { printf("tf3: %d, %d, %d\n", a,b,c); }

void call(tf_t tf, int args[], unsigned n)
{
    switch (n) {
    case 0: tf(); break;
    case 1: tf(args[0]); break;
    case 2: tf(args[0], args[1]); break;
    case 3: tf(args[0], args[1], args[2]); break;
    default: puts("Can't handle more than 3 arguments"); abort(); break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int args[] = { 1, 2 };
    call(tf2, args, sizeof args / sizeof args[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you pass `tf3` to `call()` it will print garbage as the third number, but that is the price you pay.

In principle, you shouldn't do things like this, as there might be many issues with calling conventions, but, in practice, it will most probably work.